# Como programar GUI em C?

Tags: c, gui

Quais APIs me proporcionam criar GUI utilizando C?

Pesquisei e encontrei uma chamada GTK+, porém quero saber o nome de outras bibliotecas para criar GUI utilizando C no mesmo estilo da GTK+ porém voltado para Windows.

Se possível, postem seus respectivos sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Além da [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) que você já sabe há uma infinidade de bibliotecas que podem ser usadas. Vou citar as mais conhecidas para C (não C++, conforme pedido):

- [API Win32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) (biblioteca padrão do Windows, não só a parte de GUI - [tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/start.html))
- [IUP](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/) - (*cross platform*, usada principalmente com Lua mas dá para usar com C e outras linguagens)
- [Tk](http://www.tcl.tk/) - (usada com Tcl mas pode ser usada com C e consequentemente com outras linguagens)
- [Xforms](http://xforms-toolkit.org/)
- [XVT](http://www.xvt.com/)
- [EFL](https://download.enlightenment.org/rel/libs/efl/)

Não tem como colocar exemplos em uma pergunta tão ampla, mas existem nos respectivos *sites*. Exemplos de tudo é muita coisa, colocar algum só para dizer que tem não vai fazer a resposta ser melhor.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).