# Como criar um gráfico standard map?

Tags: c, gráfico

Preciso criar um [gráfico *standard map*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_map#).

É possível plotar gráficos utilizando a linguagem C? Sei o básico de estrutura de dados, algoritmos e da linguagem c, mas não sei criar interface gráficas, apenas utilizo a janela do console (no Ubuntu) ou do prompt (no Windows). O que é necessário para criar um programa cuja interface gráfica não seja apenas no console?

Comment: Você sabe que pode votar em tudo no site também? Veja o [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível fazer isto em C. É possível fazer em qualquer linguagem de programação que aceite chamar código externo de alguma forma. Normalmente você utilizará alguma biblioteca que faça isto. É possível usar um biblioteca só para uma destas plataformas citadas na pergunta ou uma que funcione em todas. É possível usar uma mais baixo nível ou uma com mais abstrações.

Tem uma [pergunta que cita algumas bibliotecas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80324/101) não específicas para plotagem, mas que podem ser usadas para isto também. Algumas tem componentes específicos pra traçar gráficos.

Algumas pessoas preferem algo mais específico, como a [SDL](http://libsdl.org/). Ou em mais baixo nível [DirectX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX) só para Windows ou [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/) (*cross-platform*).

Talvez goste de alguma mais específica ainda como a [GNUPlot](http://www.gnuplot.info/).

Mas só tome uma decisão depois de conhecer todas o suficiente. Todas possuem vantagens e desvantagens e atende melhor cada necessidade.