# Onde posso usar GUI com .NET Core?

Tags: gui, cross-platform, .net-core

Eu já vi algumas perguntas sobre GUI [como uma em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80324/101) e outras parecidas, e fiquei curioso sobre o uso de uma GUI com .NET Core nas diversas plataformas. Sei que aceita UWP no Windows, mas não WPF ou Windows Forms. E nas outras plataformas desktop e mobile, é possível usar GUI, ou o .NET Core só funciona em console nas demais plataformas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deixando de lado Xamarin que <strike>não é .NET Core</strike> e atende o mobile para Android e iOS (roda UWP no finado Windows Phone), mas que eu acho que esses produtos vão se aproximar, é possível desenvolver GUI no .NET Core com qualquer biblioteca que acessa a API de GUI do sistema operacional que estiver usando.

Note que houve mudanças e agora Xamarin é uma das formas mais fortes para desenvolver aplicações multi plataforma através do [MAUI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455179/101).

Rem alguns projetos que estão disponíveis pela comunidade, que é uma das ideias do .NET Core, deixar a comunidade fornecer o que ela precisa além do *core* da plataforma (não ia perder o trocadilho). Vou listar os mais importantes, embora eu não os use atualmente, então não posso falar sobre os resultados, alguns não são ideais:

- [GTK#](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/) - Linux, MacOS e Windows, só para citar as principais, funciona bem em todas, mas tem algumas coisas esquisitas fora do Linux. Não foi desenvolvido para o .NET Core e sim para o Mono, mas roda no .NET Framework sem dificuldade, não tem porque ter problemas no .NET Core. São bibliotecas padrões e tem muita gente usando, tem até outras bibliotecas se baseando nela. Tem um [*binding* mais específico para o .NET Core](https://github.com/robertsundstrom/gtk-core), mas não o conheço.
- [MonoMac/Xamarin.Mac](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/monomac/) - Obviamente só funciona para MacOS, veio do Mono, mas nada impede de usar com o .NET Core da mesma forma.
- [WinForms](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/) - Sim, ele pode ser usado na implementação do Mono. Não é um dos software mais bem escritos que você já viu, mas no geral funciona em várias plataformas. E a partir do .NET Core 3 pode ser usado no Windows, e dizem na comunidade que farão o *port* para outras plataformas, mas não é fácil
- [QtSharp](https://github.com/ddobrev/QtSharp) - Ainda está longe de ser completa implementação, mas já pode usar alguma coisa da [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) (meio abandonado).
- [Avalonia](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia) - GUI que roda em várias plataformas com renderizador próprio, que é algo que tem vantagens e desvantagens.
- [Eto](https://github.com/picoe/Eto) - Uma camada que usa bibliotecas existentes. Claro que se você usar recursos do WPF, não vai rodar no Linux, se usar algo de Cocoa, não rodará no Windows.
- [Xwt](https://github.com/mono/xwt) - É uma camada em cima de outros *engines*.
- [Unity](https://unity3d.com/pt/) - É mais para jogos, mas ele não deixa de ter sua GUI.
- [Noesis](https://www.noesisengine.com/) - É paga para grandes projetos, mas roda em diversas plataformas e programa como em WPF, parece ter potencial.
- [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/) - Não é uma GUI tradicional, mas pode usar como uma, claro que uma parte não será em C# (talvez agora com o [Blazor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/288706/101) possa ser quase tudo C#).

Tem GUIs mais exotéricas e para plataformas alternativas. Lembre-se que o .NET Core deve poder rodar quase em qualquer plataforma, de dispositivos embarcados à consoles de videogames que podem ter bibliotecas específicas. E alguns projetos podem não estar em desenvolvimento.

GUI sempre foi um problema, até hoje em acho que não existe uma adequada para plataforma e tecnologia específica alguma, pior ainda que rode bem em todas, um pouco culpa dos sistemas operacionais, um pouco culpa dos produtos existentes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).