# O que é o MAUI da Microsoft?

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin-forms, gui, maui

Li que o MAUI da Microsoft é uma evolução do Xamarin.Forms. Eu gostaria de saber:

- O que muda da versão antiga para essa?
- Quais são as plataformas suportadas?
- Como é feita a migração entre o Xamarin.Forms e o MAUI?
- Já está pronto para ser utilizado em produção? Caso não, qual a data prevista para uma versão estável?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/updates/net-multiplatform-app-ui-net-maui-announced/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> O que muda da versão antiga para essa?

A maior mudança é a forma de fazer um código para todas plataformas. Agora fica mais fácil e intuitivo fazer um único projeto que rodará em todas plataformas. Isso pode ser visto em:

[image: Partes do Visual Studio mostrando como o projeto é definido]

Note que algumas partes do código podem ser especializadas para a plataforma, mas está tudo no mesmo projeto e na hora de construir ele pegará as partes relevantes para o *target* usado no momento. Fica muito mais organizado e simples.

Haverá alguma quebra de compatibilidade. Isso é necessário para alguma evolução e para corrigir alguns erros e limpar o que já se sabia que era obsoleto. Sim, muitos problemas de *design* do Xamarin Forms serão corrigidos. Não sei tudo, mas ele trabalhará muito melhor com a renderização, adotará a injeção de dependência mais amplamente, algumas coisas ficarão mais consistentes ou funcionarão de forma mais geral para encaixar bem com todas plataformas. Não acho que valha a pena tentar listar tudo aqui, até porque muda todo dia, o projeto não está fechado.

Algo que acho que vale mencionar é que haverá dois novos modelos de programação, um deles é o MVU (sim, inventaram mais um MVx :D), e o Blazor que tem um jeitão de web de programar e você poderá usá-lo para programar o MAUI. Faça do jeito que esteja mais confortável.

```
readonly State<int> count = 0;

[Body]
View body() => new StackLayout {
    new Label("Welcome to .NET MAUI!"),
    new Button(
        () => $"You clicked {count} times.",
        () => count.Value ++)
    )
};
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Xamarin/StackLayout.cs).

Vi alguns códigos como esse e ficou bem interessante usar linguagem de marcação ou de programação para construir os objetos de tela.

Obviamente que o Xamarin Forms terá muitas features normais também, continuará suportando rapidamente tudo o que vem de novo nas plataformas. Essa nova organização ajudará até o desenvolvimento interno do MAUI e contribuições da comunidade.

> Quais são as plataformas suportadas?

Há uma tabela entre as diferenças entre o Xamarin Forms e o MAUI. O que muda é o comprometimento da Microsoft com certas plataformas. A maior mudança é a adição dela oficializar o MacOS e WPF, além de melhorar as ferramentas.

E claro, ele só funcionará com o One .NET (um só *framework* para tudo), não poderá usar versões antigas ao .NET 6, principalmente os diversos *frameworks* que existiam antes do .NET 5.

[image: Tabela comparação Xamarin Forms X MAUI]

> Como é feita a migração entre o Xamarin.Forms e o MAUI?

Muito cedo para dizer.

> Já está pronto para ser utilizado em produção? Caso não, qual a data prevista para uma versão estável?

Não, ele estará disponível junto com o .NET 6 que sairá em novembro de 2021. Mas haverá *previews* ainda em 2020. Pode acompanhar o desenvolvimento e até construir por conta própria em https://github.com/dotnet/maui. Até lá pode ir usando o Xamarin.Forms que ainda tem evolução acontecendo normalmente. Podemos dizer que o MAUI é o Xamarin.Forms 6, mas ainda [está saindo o XF 5](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/wiki/Feature-Roadmap).