# O que seria algo "nativo"?

Tags: terminologia, native

Eu já li muitas postagens e artigos falando que uma linguagem, *framework*, editor ou qualquer outra coisa que seja é "nativo".

Então a minha pergunta é:

- O que é algo nativo?
- Isso é bom ou ruim?
- Há vantagens e desvantagens?

Comment: Só pra reforçar, **nw.js** também **não** é nativo, tanto Electron quanto **NW.js** usam um navegador embarcado, o Chromium, logo não é nativo, pois os componentes/elementos são gerados a partir de HTML... o que o NW.js quer dizer com "nativo" é que ele pode se comunicar com coisas nativas, geralmente através dos seus addons, isso é feito em "tempo de instalação", mas tecnicamente isso é meio que possivel em Electron também, só que aumenta os caminhos, já que passa pelo node.js, então para resumir, NW.js é hibrido e possui componentes "nativos", mas não é de fato nativo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> O que é algo nativo?

Depende do contexto que é usado. Quase tudo o que ver por aí será no contexto do mobile, é comparando apenas um que vai direto no sistema operacional ou se é web, mas não é o único.

É uma pena porque algumas pessoas nem conhecem mais os fundamentos, o que é correto no sentido amplo. Olhar só para um contexto é o que causa muitas pessoas não entenderem mais o que está acontecendo com suas aplicações.

Nem sempre é fácil usar o termo de forma correta para classificar algo. Não há uma definição tão clara da linha que separa algo nativo ou não.

## Termo original

Nativo pode ser rodar o software diretamente na máquina, sem intermediários. Algumas pessoas podem considerar que pode ter algum intermediário momentâneo como acontece com o [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101). Grosso modo podemos dizer que é executar de forma binária.

Ele se opõe para alguma forma de interpretação ou virtualização de ambiente que não gere um código binário que seja exatamente o que o processador entende.

Mas nem sempre é simples dizer o que está rodando nativo ou não. Exemplo simples:

- C, C++, Rust, Swift, D e Delphi são claramente nativos (nas implementações mais conhecidas, nada impede ser diferente).
- PHP até a data que escrevo claramente não é nativo (na implementação que todo mundo usa, isso vai mudar).
- C# ou Java/Kotlin rodam código nativo, mas a forma mais usada precisa de um processo que gera esse código nativo na hora que vai executar. [Isso não é interpretação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125588/101) ([outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22647/101)). De fato, é possível que esse mecanismo abra oportunidade de otimização que código nativos normais não podem ter. Eu considero nativo, mas há quem argumente que não é tanto assim. Algumas pessoas podem reclamar que a memória é gerenciada por um *runtime*, mas isso eu duvido que possa dizer que elimine de forma direta que seja nativo.
- Python, Ruby, Lua, Harbour, Perl parecem interpretadas. Mas é comum que elas sejam pré-compiladas antes (não em todas as implementações, algumas usar JITter, outras usam até a geração AOT). Isso torna-as nativas? Não. Ainda haverá interpretação de um *bytecode* em uma VM. É diferente do item anterior que apesar de ter uma interpretação de um [*bytecode*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138577/101), ocorre só para gerar o código nativo, o código de máquina.
- JavaScript é mais complicado porque ele interpreta o código fonte, mas quase todas as implementações rodam em um JITter, então a execução ocorre de forma nativa. É nativo? O custo para gerar o nativo é bem grande, em alguns casos pode demorar mais que acontece em uma linguagem de *script* pura que roda em uma VM interpretando um *bytecode* (que é bem mais fácil).

## Termo popular

Existe um outro contexto que é sobre o acesso à API do sistema operacional. Novamente estamos falando sobre ter algum código intermediando do acesso ou não. E também há controvérsias do que é nativo.

Por exemplo, a Qt é uma biblioteca de acesso ao sistema de janelas e desenho tela multi plataforma. É nativo? Mais ou menos. Depende do que considera. Acessa as APIs do sistema operacional, mas é uma camada em cima dela para fazer certas partes de um jeito diferente.

O mesmo vale para mobile. Se acessar Android com Java/Kotlin em geral fará acesso nativo à bibliotecas do SO. Mas se usar Xamarin, que é C#, o acesso é nativo. Em geral considera-se que sim, há uma camada, mas tudo é permitido igual se fizesse com Java/Kotlin, e acontece tudo do mesmo jeito, essencialmente com a mesma performance.

E se usar Xamarin Forms (futuro [MAUI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455179/101)), ainda é nativo? Parece que sim, não muda muito, é só mais uma camada. Mas há pequenas limitações. Então se torna mais difícil dizer.

Se for acessar por alguma tecnologia web ainda é nativo? Geralmente considera-se que não. Você tem uma forma muito diferente de fazer e que por acaso a tecnologia renderizadora usada (algo que é parte de um navegador de internet) acessará algo do sistema operacional, mas não é sua aplicação diretamente, então não seria nativo. Muda a semântica do que fazer. Acessa por uma API completamente diferente.

Quase tudo o que for pesquisar por aí só será classificado como não nativo se for web, e nativo o resto. Não é uma boa classificação, mas é aceitável, as pessoas entendem assim.

> Isso é bom ou ruim?

Não dá para afirmar isso. Veja próximo item.

> Há vantagens e desvantagens?

Claro, como tudo. E depende do contexto, vou tentar misturar os dois que eu citei.

Nativo é vantajoso:

- É bem mais rápido (quase sempre).
- Tende a ser mais leve mandar uma aplicação, mas isso depende um pouco, tem casos que é pior, difícil cravar se isso é vantagem e se acontece, depende com o que está comparando.
- Permite fazer tudo que a API nativa permite sempre, e está o mais atualizado possível.
- A experiência do usuário é igual em toda a plataforma, pode-se dizer que seja mais perfeita.
- Algumas plataformas dão vantagens para aplicações nativas.

Nativo é desvantajoso:

- Nativo não pode ser usado em outras plataformas e se precisa fazer para várias pode custar caro e demorar mais fazer para cada uma. Ainda que tenha alguns truques que podem minimizar isso, como citei acima.
- Nativo pode ser uma forma bruta de fazer e ser mais difícil de codificar que uma forma mais abstrata, uma camada extra.
- Dependendo de como o não nativo é feito e da plataforma, pode ser mais fácil atualizar *web por exemplo), mas não é difícil para o nativo, as pessoas só não estão tão acostumadas.
- No contexto de web a experiência pode ser interessante no sentido que todo mundo está acostumado com web, não importa que dispositivo ou sistema operacional usa. O problema é que cada site/app web usa um jeito diferente de fazer, o que é ruim, então o nativo seria mais vantajoso por dar uma base de como a UI deve ser. Não é fácil cravar essas coisas.
- Em geral o nativo precisa de alguma forma de instalação, mas isso depende um pouco, não é tão ruim quanto as pessoas costumam fazer (não podemos colocar como desvantagem o fato das pessoas fazerem errado).

Note que as desvantagens têm mais a ver com a API, o fato de rodar o executável nativo, se olhar só esse aspecto, ele tende ser só vantajoso. Algumas tecnologias não nativas podem ter outras vantagens que compensam o fato de ser algo lento, ter um intermediário.

Algumas questões dependem muito do que está se olhando. Eu até usei um exemplo, mas tem vários casos. Tem soluções que parece ser mais limitado, mais difícil fazer de um jeito, mas dá para fazer de outro jeito.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então algo nativo é algo que acesse diretamente o OS sem precisar de um software trabalhando antes fazendo a ligação de um com o outro, é isso? Sendo assim, linguagens com interpretadores como por exemplo Python não são nativos e linguagens com compiladores são nativos?

Comment: Não podemos afirmar isso, não há uma definição clara. è basicamente isso, mas não tem claro que tipo de intermediário é possível ter, por isso que eu dou exemplo de casos que tem intermediários, mas ele sendo fino, não mudando a semântica básica, não te limitando, ainda pode ser nativo. Python não costuma ser nativa, mas há implementação dela que dá pra dizer que é. O gerenciamento de memória não ainda não é tanto assim, mas o resto é. Tem Python que até o gerenciamento dem memória é mais próximo do nativo, mas aí eu diria que é outra linguagem parecida com Python, e não Python em si.

Comment: Enfim, é muito complicado traçar uma linha para dizer o que é nativo ou não. Alguns casos são bem claros que são nativos. C++ é (em quase todas implementações). C# eu diria que é, algumas implementações certamente, mas não em 100% dos aspectos. JavaScript parece não ser, mas as implementações não são tão diferentes assim de C# ou Java. Mas é um pouco. Mas JS sozinho não quer dizer muito, ele junto com HTML e CSS não usa o sistema de telas do sistema operacional. TypeScript á nativo? È uma forma tão diferente de tudo isso. Mas TS é JS, e agora?

Answer (score -3):

Nos dias de hoje tem se popularizado cada vez mais oque é chamado de desenvolvimento hibrido, seja em plataformas mobile ou desktop. Sempre que vamos desenvolver um software nós escolhemos para que plataformas iremos desenvolve-lo e qual Sistemas Operacionais iremos dar suporte, por exemplo no mobile temos Android e iOS, no desktop temos OSx (Apple), Windows e Linux. Se optarmos por desenvolver Android então iremos programar em Java, se optarmos por desenvolver iOS iremos programar em Swift e assim por diante. Mas e se pudéssemos programar apenas uma vez e esse código servir tanto pra Android quanto pra iOS? Não seria uma maravilha? Foi ai que começaram a surgir as plataformas hibridas, no que mais se popularizou podemos citar o mobile com ReactNative e Flutter, onde você programa apenas uma vez e o código vai funcionar tanto para Android quanto para iOS. Agora imagine que você precisa trabalhar com alguns recursos que só existem no Android ou só no iOS? então você não pode mais usar recursos híbridos, é ai que entra o chamado "nativo" onde você usa recursos que só existe no Android por exemplo. Quando falamos em programar nativo estamos falando basicamente em trabalhar com a linguagem oficial, daquela plataforma, no caso do Android o Java ou Kotlin, e do iOS o Swift. Outro exemplo que podemos dar é o desenvolvimento Desktop, se nós programarmos com Java, nosso sistema ira funcionar em qualquer sistema operacional, seja ele Windows, Linux ou outro, mas agora imagine que você queira acessar funções especificas do Windows, então você terá que usar a API nativa do Windows que é feita em C# (Microsoft). Trabalhar com nativo é muito vantajoso pois você ganha muita performace, pois você esta trabalhando diretamente com os componentes e com a linguagem do sistema operacional, porém em contraponto você precisara programar seu aplicativo em 2 linguagens diferentes, ou seja, tera que fazer ele em Java pra Android e depois refazer em Swift para iOS. A vantagem que você tem usando hibrido é a maior liberdade de trabalhar com os componentes do sistema operacional especifico e a performace, mas como eu falei, em contraponto você precisa reprogramar o App, então tudo vai depender da sua necessidade.

Answer (score -4):

As aplicações nativas são desenvolvidas para um sistema específico (**Android e iOS**) e são descarregadas para um dispositivo móvel a partir de uma loja de aplicações. O seu desenvolvimento faz-se em linguagens de programação específicas, como o **Swift para iOS e o Kotlin para Android**.

Comment: Jaime, as "aplicações nativas" não são exclusivas de Mobile e a pergunta em si solicita a definição do que é nativo.

Comment: Desculpe o equivoco, quis da um exemplo de aplicações nativas no Android e no IOS.